# Routes not executing : camel / fuse / activemq

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am following some tutorials [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.2.1/html/Deploying_into_a_Web_Server/ch02s03.html) towards understanding how I can use camel routes on a deployed Jboss EAP 6.4 server. The goal of my current application is fairly simple, in that I want to read from an ActiveMQ topic, and log it out. Below code summarizes my actions:

```
package com.mycompany;

import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.cdi.ContextName;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;

@ApplicationScoped
@Startup
@ContextName("com.mycompany")
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("### we are in the main");

        final ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        getContext().addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(factory));

        System.out.println("#### route being called");
        from("jms:topic:activemq/topic/myTopic").log("###### we are in here with this message ${body}");

    }
}
```

I also have a Launcher class to test my routes:

```
package com.mycompany;

import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(final String... args) throws Exception {
        final Main main = new Main();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new CamelRoute());
        main.run(args);
    }
}
```

If I start my routes via the following maven command, I can receive all messages that come to the activemq topic. So I know that if I manually start the route, I can at least retrieve the data.

```
mvn clean install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.mycompany.Launcher
```

However, once I deploy my application to the server ( as a jar, enabled ), the same cannot be said. None of my system.out statements are noticeable in the logs. I almost feel as if I am missing additional configuration to "jump-start" the application.

Note: I added the EJB annotations for startup in the CamelRoute class, but that did not solve the problem. Am I missing something obvious here?

Output from the jboss eap 6.4 log once I deploy the jar:

```
04:18:21,390 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (HttpManagementService-threads - 49) JBAS014900: Content added at location C:\bin\jboss-fuse\jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\data\content\99\f271f8372007ee6a2bce37668656acb80ef160\content
04:18:21,427 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "camel-java-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" (runtime-name: "camel-java-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
04:18:21,431 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.camel] (MSC service thread 1-4) @ContextName annotation found
04:18:21,442 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "camel-java-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found.
04:18:21,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 49) JBAS015859: Deployed "camel-java-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" (runtime-name : "camel-java-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
```

Comment: Have you got it to work without running on the server? I suspect your app dies as soon as it starts up. You need to ensure it runs forever. Check the doc for this.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti right, the maven command i mention above is running without the server. it lasts forever, there is no end. && when deployed to the eap server, I see that the .jar file was "deployed" but none of the system.out statements are going through.

Comment: Best to check with the fuse team. It is a commercial app.

Comment: EAP won't have Camel components-- you must install the Fuse bits.  If you're using Wildfly, then it would be the Wildfly-Camel subsystem.
Once those bits are in place, the app server is Camel-enabled.

Comment: @RickJWagner rick, it was my understanding that eap 6.4 comes with fuse? In my local enviornment, I can see a fusepatch and fuse-6.3jar . Are you referring to something else that I might be missing? Any way to test out I have everything I need?

Comment: check when the Jar is getting deployed, your camelcontext starts. Does the class getting scanned by your application context for annotation processing and subsequently starting the camelcontext?

Comment: @sakura I added the jboss output to the question. i can see the wildfly extension be loaded, it just does nothing. even the camel tab is not present in the eap ( by default, it is not present if no camel routes are found )

Comment: Hi @angryip.  One way to do it would be to have a look at $JBOSS_HOME/quickstarts/camel.  If you see some example applications there, you have Fuse bits in place.
The next step would be to try one of the quickstarts. Start your server, use Maven to compile one of the quickstarts, and copy the resulting binary to the server's deploy directory.  The server log will let you know if things go smoothly after that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pointer in your log output which indicates the likely cause of this issue:

```
JBAS016012: Deployment deployment "camel-java-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" contains CDI annotations but beans.xml was not found.
```

You'll need to make sure you add a `META-INF/beans.xml` to your JAR. Implicit bean archives were not added until CDI 1.1. EAP 6.x / JavaEE 6 uses CDI 1.0. If beans.xml is not present within the deployment, your Camel CDI application will never be boostrapped and started.